# Совместить данные из лист бокс и сохранить их в txt файл

Tags: delphi

есть имена файлов по типу

```
test1.jpg
test2.jpg
...
test35000.jpg
```

хранятся имена в листбоксе, мне нужно что бы они добавились в код по типу

```
send_photo_file(chat_id, 'test1.jpg')
send_photo_file(chat_id, 'test2.jpg')
```

в тхт файл

Comment: Используйте цикл for и функцию format для образования строки с числом

Answer (score 0):

ListBox1.Items.SaveToFile('listbox1.txt');

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]